# ArcGIS JS API 3.21 InfoTemplate ZoomIn Button

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Has anyone had luck attaching a click event to a custom button built in the HTML of the InfoTemplate? Here's my InfoTemplate HTML:

```
uploadInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate ({
    title: "",
    content: "<strong>Segment:</strong> ${segment}" +
             "<hr/>" +
             "<strong>Time:</strong> <i>${dateTime}</i>" +
             "<div style='width: 100%; text-align:right;'>" +
                 "<input class='zoomButton' type='button' value='Zoom to' />" +
             "</div>"
});
```

I then have hidden items on the default InfoTemplate, i.e. the zoomTo link. I want to simply replace the zoomTo's functionality with a button, to make it look a little nicer.

Comment: Do you want to just change the icon? Or change the functionality of what happens when you click it?  Or remove it and add your own magic button?

Comment: @BjornSvensson Thank you for the response.  I want to make a button that will trigger the same action as the 'Zoom to' link does.  I.E. when the button is clicked upon it will perform the zoom action.

Comment: @MatthewDewell Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I think I went a different route than using the InfoTemplate.  It's been over a year now. :D  Sorry.